# Is it bad practice to have a constructor with entirely optional parameters?

Tags: c#

While designing a class structure for a C# project, I thought about an interesting question that I was hoping to get some insight on before finalizing my design. Here's a template design of the concept I'm talking about:

```
class TemplateClass
{
    public TemplateClass(int input1 = 0, string input2 = "")
    {
        field1 = input1;
        field2 = input2;
    }
    public TemplateClass()
    {
        field1 = 0;
        field2 = "";
    }
    public int field1;
    public string field2;
}
```

It seems like an incredibly convenient design for the purpose of what I'm doing, but I'm curious if this is considered bad practice for any reason.

Comment: I would say the empty constructor has no purpose in your example. It duplicates the default values.

Comment: The benefit as I see it, and of course I can be entirely incorrect about this, is that you can input any number of inputs to create the class. For instance, in my actual project, I have a class with 8 member fields, and when I'm creating a class, I sometimes don't have data for the last 3 or 4 fields. So this design seemed convenient.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't define a constructor. Instead use `new TemplateClass { field1 = 1, field2 = "2" }`

Comment: Ok, but what's the point of having that second constructor with no parameters? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: @ChaosPandion actually some reflection based frameworks will still 'require' the default constructor even in situations like this, the signature is still different and the generated IL is very different.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: A realio-trulio public no-argument constructor is required for a type to meet the `new` constraint of a generic type parameter.

Comment: The bad design here is the public fields! Those should be properties, and consider whether they should be read-only.

Comment: Thank you all for the insight, I'm definitely not the strongest at class design, and I appreciate the food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have your fields public anyway I don't see any value that your constructors add to it since you can specify them during construction:

```
new TemplateClass();
new TemplateClass { field1 = 17 };
new TemplateClass { field2 = "hello" };
new TemplateClass { field2 = "world", field1 = 42 };
```

The code for your class would reduce to this:

```
class TemplateClass
{
    public int field1 = 0;
    public string field2 = "";
}
```

Note, unless you are planning to use these fields as a `ref` argument somewhere, I would also turn them into properties like `public int Field1 { get; set; }`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I'm so used to a "Constructor, Getters, Setters, ToString" class design that I didn't even consider the redundancy associated with this approach.

Comment: Stuff like this makes me wish C# had [record types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39) .  They're planning on it, some day.